# Trying to install microsoft.aspnet.web.optimization in ASP.NET MVC project getting error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, nuget-package

I am trying to install `microsoft.aspnet.web.optimization` in an ASP.NET MVC project, but I'm getting this error:

> Install-Package: An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Dapper.1.60.6' from source
>   ...ABC\packages.

where project name is ABC.

How to resolve this issue? Any idea would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Please check Below link That will help you out :

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/

in Package manager try below code :

Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization -Version 1.1.3

in .net CLI try this :

dotnet add package Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization --version 1.1.3

Comment: again getting error An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'Dapper.1.60.6'

Comment: Please refer this link install Dapper once if you still found issue try to repair studio from package that will help you out : 
  https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper/issues/975